# how can call value in jquery function in onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want add value in jquery function an post it to my php file. I call my jquery function whit onclick event but i don't know how can add value.
I have this input tag:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"  />
```

and my onlick event this is:

```
<span onClick="previewed_files(); checkDb();">start</span>
```

and my checkDb function it is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    function checkDb(adscode){
        $.post('myphp.php',{adscode: adscode},function(data){
            $('#mydiv').html(data);}

                        );
            }
  </script>
```

now I can't call value from input by id code in my checkDb() function in onclick event.
please help me. thank you

Comment: You call checkDb() with no parameters, so "adscode" is undefined when the function is executed. Assuming your code (in $code) does not contain single or double quotes, I'd try <span onClick="previewed_files(); checkDb('<?php echo $code; ?>');">start</span>

Comment: I'm using this code but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function checkDb(adscode){
    $.post('myphp.php',{adscode: adscode, value: $('#code').val()},function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html(data);});
}
</script>
```

Comment: work for me : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q9z1dgL/2/) and [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/nfwtu8nf?inspect)

Answer (score 0):

You must check for `ajax tutorials` to get value in php. You cant get parameter value in function untill you pass in the function.

to get value of hidden variable -

```
var value = jQuery('#code').val();
```

Now, you can use this variable in your funciton.

Comment: thank you I add your code in my function now how can use this variable? sorry I don't know jquery well